# What is the best solution for letting both Macs and PCs access digital images and videos on a network?

Tags: mac, nas, windows-home-server, mybook

I'm looking for a simple way to share digital images and videos over a network to both Macs and PCs. I'm currently looking into three options: NAS, WD MyBook Mirror drives attached to a router, or an HP WHS product like the Data Vault.

I'm looking for something easy to implement that allows for drive mirroring but also has good performance for both Macs and PCS. I've read that the HP WHS devices rebalance on their own schedules, making them useless for streaming video, and hope someone can definitively confirm or deny this as it's a dealbreaker if true. Any other suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I run a WHS at home (self built) and I can thoroughly recommend it.

WHS does rebalance data across drives (aswell as mirroring if you request) but I've never had any issues streaming HD video off them. So far as I can tell the "Drive Extender Service"(which is what does the rebalancing) only runs when the server is idle or only balances disks that are not otherwise in use.
If you leave the server on 24/7 anyway(I don't) then the server should only have to balance after you've copied data over anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dual drive enclosure attached to my mac with FW800, shared across a gigabit ethernet network to my windows machine. I am only using it as simple storage, but raid solutions exist. This setup works very well for my needs; streaming itunes across the network and network storage.

Enclosure Link: [RAID 0/ JBOD version](http://eshop.macsales.com/Customized_Pages/Framework.cfm?page=mepal_splash_raid.html) , [RAID 1 version](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/firewire/usb/raid_1/Gmax)